# Сохранение процессов в Unity3D

Tags: unity3d, анимация

Здравствуйте! На сцене присутствуют анимированные объекты. К примеру вращающаяся карусель или секундная стрелка и тд. Анимация идет по кругу (Always Animate). Так как я не знаю как записать текущий кадр анимации объекта -при загрузке сохранного файла, анимация начинается с нулевого кадра т.е. самого начала. Как при сохранении записать текущий кадр анимации объекта и продолжить проигрывание при загрузке? Заранее спасибо!

**Обновление**

Через Аnimation. Много объектов вторичных на сцене, но анимация важна. Вот например солнце с простой поэтапной анимацией.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Анимация какая? через `Аnimation` или `Mecanic` (через `Animator`) ? так-то у анимаций есть только время. Может всё же записывать его?

Comment: Так всё же, почему хотите записать именно кадр, а не время , а потом исполнять его с того места именно основываясь на времени? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationState-time.html

Comment: Если записывать время, анимация разных объектов продолжит воспроизводится синхронно? Если да, то подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать.